# SQL Delete records in a loop

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to loop through a list of comma seperated ids and delete them one by one in mysql. something like this:-

```
Begin
for idToDelete in (113,114) LOOP
delete from `myTable`
where `ID`=idToDelete;
END LOOP;
END;
```

How can I make this work? the for in thing is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete multiple records by use of `IN` clause:

```
DELETE FROM `myTable` WHERE `ID` IN (YOUR COMMA SEPARATED IDS);
```

Why need of loop?

Answer (score 1):

If your CSV list is transferred into the query as a parameter - single string literal, then use

```
DELETE 
FROM myTable
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, 'idsToDelete');
```

i.e. in particular shown case

```
DELETE 
FROM myTable
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, '113,114');
```

If this list is inserted immediately into query text before send it to MySQL, look the solution provided by [harish sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5026957/harish-sharma).